# £ Sign on python SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, encode

I am trying to inject into a query, a string in the following way:

```
value = '£'
query = """select * from table where condition = '{0}';""".format(value)
```

the problem is the result of this formatting is:

> select * from table where condition = '\xc2\xa3';

Since I will use this query with sqlalchemy, I need the encoded characers to appear as the actual pund sign.

Any ideas on how I can makes this query look like this?:

> select * from table where condition = '£';

I am using postgres 3.5 and python 2.7.6

Also if I try the following:

```
'\xc2\xa3'.decode('utf-8')
```

the result is:

> u'\xa3'

Comment: Well the byte sequence `"\xc2\xa3"` is *already* the pound sign `£` (utf-8 encoded), so it doesn't make much sense to ask how to turn the former into the latter. Are you asking how to get a `unicode` object from that? Or, are you asking how to *display* the string so that a `£` will appear in your console?

Comment: Just use unicode literals in your python2 code: `from __future__ import unicode_literals`.

Comment: Youre right univerio, it aually works fine if I just pass the string as such (even if when displayed it shows a weird character) sql interprets it correctly, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Unicode for a pound sign is 163 (decimal) or A3 in hex, so the following should work.

```
print u"\xA3"
```

Oirigin answer: [What encoding do I need to display a GBP sign (pound sign) using python on cygwin in Windows XP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705434/what-encoding-do-i-need-to-display-a-gbp-sign-pound-sign-using-python-on-cygwi)